# How would I go about partitioning an array in MIPS assembly?

Tags: arrays, loops, assembly, mips

For a program I'm working on, I need to write a subprogram that partitions the array based on an input from the user (in main).  So basically if the original array was [4.2, -1.2, 16.5, 12.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9] and the user entered 6.1 as the partition value, the two arrays would be [4.2, -1.2, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9] and [16.5, 12.3].  What I'm confused on is that I know I need to use two loops and I know that I'll have to compare the values using `c.lt.d`, `bc1f` and stuff like that but I'm not exactly clear on how to do it properly.  Can anyone help me out with this?

Also, this is the basic jist of the subprogram:

```
###########################################################
#       Subprogram Description
#
#       'partition_array'
#
#   1. Determine how many values in source are < partition value
#   2. Allocate two arrays on heap (one w/ values < partition value,
#      one >= partition value)
#   3. Copy the values from the source array into appropriate destination array
#   4. Return base address and length of both
#
###########################################################
#       Arguments In and Out of subprogram
#
#   $sp source array base address (IN)
#   $sp+4   source array length (IN)
#   $sp+8   partition value, double-precision (IN)
#   $sp+16  "less" array base address (OUT)
#   $sp+20  "less" array length (OUT)
#   $sp+24  "greater" array base address (OUT)
#   $sp+28  "greater" array length (OUT)
###########################################################
        .data

###########################################################
        .text
partition_array:

partition_array_end:

    jr $ra  #return to calling location
###########################################################
```

Comment: Inefficient calling conventions. The MIPS ABI's all use use a few registers for the first few parameters. These sort of decisions will collectively defeat the point of hand-written assembly.

Comment: @Kaz Are you answering my question or just complaining about MIPS?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on my own.  Not too difficult, just a lot of planning.

```
###########################################################
#        Arguments In and Out of subprogram
#
#   $sp     source array base address (IN)
#   $sp+4   source array length (IN)
#   $sp+8   partition value, double-precision (IN)
#   $sp+16  "less" array base address (OUT)
#   $sp+20  "less" array length (OUT)
#   $sp+24  "greater" array base address (OUT)
#   $sp+28  "greater" array length (OUT)
###########################################################
#       Register Usage
#   $t0     array base address
#   $t1     array size
#   $t2     "less" array size
#   $t3     "greater" array size
#   $t4     "less" array base address
#   $t5     "greater" array base address
#   $f4     temporary (double)
#   $f12    partition value
###########################################################
        .data

###########################################################
        .text
partition_array:
    lw $t0, 0($sp)  #load array base address
    lw $t1, 4($sp)  #load array size
    lw $f12, 8($sp)  #load partition value

loop1:
    blez $t1, continue  #branch if reached end of array

    l.d $f4, 0($t0)  #load double @ array address
    c.lt.d $f4, $f12  #compare and set flag if < partition value

    bc1t less  #branch to "less" array if true
    bc1f greater  #branch to "greater" array if false

less:
    addi $t2, $t2, 1  #add to "less" size
    addi $t0, $t0, 8  #move to next array address
    addi $t1, $t1, -1  #decrement counter
    b loop1

greater:
    addi $t3, $t3, 1  #add to "greater" size
    addi $t0, $t0, 8  #move to next array address
    addi $t1, $t1, -1  #decrement counter
    b loop1

continue:
    li $v0, 9  #create array for "less"
    sll $a0, $t2, 3
    syscall
    move $v0, $t4  #move "less" array base address

    li $v0, 9  #create array for "greater"
    sll $a0, $t3, 3
    syscall
    move $v0, $t5  #move "greater" array base address

    sw $t2, 20($sp)  #store "less" array size on stack
    sw $t3, 28($sp)  #store "greater" array size on stack

continue_loop:
    blez $t1, partition_array_end  #branch if reached end of array

    l.d $f4, 0($t0)  #load double @ array address
    c.lt.d $f4, $f12  #compare and set flag if < partition value

    bc1t create_less  #branch to "less" array if true
    bc1f create_greater  #branch to "greater" array if false

create_less:
    s.d $f4, 0($t4)  #store double @ array address
    addi $t0, $t0, 8  #move to next main array address
    addi $t1, $t1, -1  #decrement counter
    addi $t4, $t4, 8  #move to next "less" array address

    b continue_loop

create_greater:
    s.d $f4, 0($t5)  #store double @ array address
    addi $t0, $t0, 8  #move to next main array address
    addi $t1, $t1, -1  #decrement counter
    addi $t5, $t5, 8  #move to next "less" array address

    b continue_loop

partition_array_end:
    sw $t4, 16($sp)  #store "less" array base address on stack
    sw $t5, 24($sp)  #store "greater" array base address on stack

    jr $ra  #return to calling location
```

Comment: You can remove the `bc1t less` because you'll just "fall through" to the less code. As a refinement, use `c.lt.d $f12,$f4` and `bc1t greater` to use positive logic. Likewise, for the second use of `c.lt.d` later on. For both, you'd only need _both_ `bc1t/bc1f` branches if the `==` condition were being treated differently than `<`